# How deep can a recursive call get before I get stackoverflow exception?

Tags: c#, .net

How deep can a recursive call go before a stackoverflow exception is thrown in c#?

Is this a constant value or machine dependent? I am writing a small application that processes a tree structure recursively and I am scared of getting a stackoverflow exception on some machines.

The three can have 50 levels at most so around 50 recursive calls one after another. Is this much?

Comment: I haven't ever got such an error with a proper code; only with infinite loops or similar.

Comment: Impossible to say. Stack size can be changed, Default is different in different contexts (desktop app, ASP.NET 32/64 bit) and we don't know how much stack each call you (because of stack allocated variables and/or explicit stack allocated arrays with stackalloc). In general should be easier to rewrite such function in a non-recurisve form (a tree iterator is easy to implement with yield without any recursion)

Comment: depends on amout of parameters and their type.
From lessons learned - if you recursion nested level more than 10 - its time to look for another implementation

Comment: Not 50, thousands.  Recursive algorithms should never be worse than O(logN).  Should not be a problem with tree walks unless your tree is hopelessly imbalanced.  Which is a bug.